# How to render sitemap.xml in SAP Commerce Spartacus site?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront, hybris-data-hub

I was wondering if anyone knows how to get the `sitemap.xml` functionality working in Spartacus site like how it was working in `yacceleratorstorefront/sitemap.xml`.

Looks like SAP Commerce Support team is still having this functionality in their roadmaps. But we need to implement `sitemap.xml` for making the site live

We tried implementing the `sitemap.xml` in same way like other pages in Spartacus site. But it is getting rendered as HTML if we view the source. But we need to load the `sitemap.xml` file in XML format only when we view the source.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Serving Spartacus-based site is a bit complicated. There are other workarounds.

**First suggestion**:
Use SAP Commerce capabilities to generate `sitemap.xml` files. Save them to your web server and configure your web server (Nginx/Apache) to serve them at your backend.

[Source for the docs](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE/4c33bf189ab9409e84e589295c36d96e/8adb25b386691014af16eb036124f349.html)

**Second suggestion**
If your Spartacus storefront is running on an Express.js or Node.js server, modify it to serve your sitemap.xml file. Use a task scheduler to generate the `sitemap.xml` file regularly and save it to your server.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your `sitemap.xml` to be rendered as HTML if you view the source, only the true xml asset, just place that in `/assets/sitemap` and define it as an asset.

angular.json -> architect/projectname/build/options

```
"assets": [
  //...
  "src/assets",
  { "glob": "**/*sitemap.xml", "input": "src/assets/sitemap", "output": "/" }
],
```